# Linux partitioning problem

Tags: partition, fdisk, linux

I am using cfdisk to repartition my hdd as from OS install I only got 1 big partition a swap.
I wanted to resize the big partition to 1 GB /boot and use the rest of the space for an extended partition.

After I do cfdisk, I recheck the partitions with fdisk -l and I get these:

```
    Disk /dev/sda: 320 GB, 320070320640 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System 
/dev/sda3               1       38443   308785365    f  Extended LBA
Warning: Partition 3 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2           38455       38698     1951897   82  Linux swap
/dev/sda1   *       38699       38913   311349654   83  Linux
```

My problem is the Warning message, I think I know the cause, I think its because of **sda1 Blocks** size. **How could that be soo big if Start and End interval is small**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want a 1Gb `/boot`? The only things that go there are kernel and and grub files.
Unless you are keeping 100's of kernels 100Mb `/boot` is good enough.

As far as the message goes, did you reboot after resizing it?